# unable to install packages in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting jsonlib

```
Using cached jsonlib-1.6.1.tar.gz (43 kB)
Could not build wheels for jsonlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: jsonlib
    Running setup.py install for jsonlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Shankhya13\\AppData\\Local\
\Temp\\pip-install-5t7gtx9m\\jsonlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Shankhya13\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5t7gtx9m\\jsonlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=g
etattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' in
stall --record 'C:\Users\Shankhya13\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y8xv3b4p\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --
install-headers 'C:\Users\Shankhya13\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\jsonlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Shankhya13\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5t7gtx9m\jsonlib\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying jsonlib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_jsonlib' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
tells everything you need to know.

Comment: Just as the error message implies, you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 the error message even provides a link to get it